# TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

I am running sql query in teradata and want to populate the output in excel. I have below code, where row has data set from SQL. First column is date,

```
for p in (row):
    column_num = 1
    for item in  p:
        _ = ws0.cell(row=row_number, column=column_num, value=item)
        column_num = column_num + 1
        row_number = row_number + 1
```

This code errors out:

`TypeError: 'datetime.date' object is not iterable`

If I change the code to

```
data = str(row)
for p in data:
    column_num = 1
    for item in  p:
        _ = ws0.cell(row=row_number, column=column_num, value=item)
        column_num = column_num + 1
        row_number = row_number + 1
```

Then error does not occur but excel is populated in one column instead of row. Below is output of my SQL query

Row 1:

```
[2017-09-01, 35053479.1102, 230870, 5372148.7940]
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tU6p.jpg)

Comment: Did you use SQLAlchemy?

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation like your code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are not setting back your column_num to `0` after your loop. Therefore, you're not only adding rows.

Comment: My indentation was correct. It just was not pasted in the comment section.

Comment: Thanks scharette.  Hi gilbertxenodike i am not using SQLAlchemy. I am using teradata module

Comment: indentation is still wrong, add a space in front of both for loops having only 3 spaces

Comment: @SuhasJadhav accept edits and please accept the answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have 4 spaces in my code.  It is just copy paste issue in the comment                data = str(row)
for p in (data):
    column_num = 1

    for item in  p:


         _= ws0.cell(row = row_number,column= column_num,value = item)
         column_num = column_num+1

     row_number = row_number + 1

Comment: Now the code is ok, did my post fixed your problem ?

Comment: Nope it did not fix

Comment: is there a way i can send you excel file whihc was generated. That will make it easy to understand.

Comment: You can add an image in your question if it helps understanding

Comment: i have added the image. Please check and let me know if you can help